# Counting the number of occurrences of each item in a list

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I have a streaming input which has repeated values. I can use any data structure but I have to count the number of occurence of each element. Suppose I have a list of mobile phone suppliers like the following:

```
Apple
Nokia
Samsung
Apple
LG
Nokia
HTC
Android
Apple
Nokia
Nokia
Apple
Samsung
```

I have to build any data structure preferably a map with details like

```
Apple,4
Nokia,4
Samsung,2
LG,1
Android,1
```

I am not sure whether this is optimal. Is there a better solution than this?
In fact I have yet to write the above as a code. So better code will also help.

Comment: "Counting the list items" seems misleading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I would use a `Map<String, Integer>`. I would wrap the `add` in something like this:

```
private static void incrementValue(Map<String, Integer> counters, String toAdd) {
    Integer currValue = counters.get(toAdd);
    if (currValue == null)
        counters.put(toAdd, 1);
    else
        counters.put(toAdd, currValue+1);
}
```

Or without generics:

```
private static void incrementValue(Map counters, String toAdd) {
    Integer currValue = (Integer) counters.get(toAdd);
    if (currValue == null)
        counters.put(toAdd, 1);
    else
        counters.put(toAdd, currValue+1);
}
```

Comment: A small information...I can't use Generics as I have to use Java 1.4

Answer (score 4):

Since it was mentioned by the questioner that generics could not be used, as the target platform was Java 1.4, one could use the [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) which doesn't use generics.

The [answer by pjp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059114/counting-the-list-items/1059159#1059159) mentions that a Bag can be used.

It turns out, the Apache Commons Collections has a [`Bag`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/Bag.html) which has a [`getCount`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/Bag.html#getCount(java.lang.Object)) method which will return the count of a certain object that was added to the `Bag`.

The following is an example that [`add`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/Bag.html#add(java.lang.Object))s some `Integer` objects to a [`HashBag`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/bag/HashBag.html), and counts how many of each `Integer` object that the `Bag` contains:

```
Bag b = new HashBag();

b.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
b.add(Integer.valueOf(2));
b.add(Integer.valueOf(2));
b.add(Integer.valueOf(3));

System.out.println("Count for 1: " + b.getCount(Integer.valueOf(1)));
System.out.println("Count for 2: " + b.getCount(Integer.valueOf(2)));
System.out.println("Count for 3: " + b.getCount(Integer.valueOf(3)));
```

The results were:

```
Count for 1: 1
Count for 2: 2
Count for 3: 1
```

(I should add a disclaimer that this code was actually compiled and run on Java 6, but I believe I've only used features which were present from the pre-Java 5 days.)

Comment: thats brilliant...I would like to vote for you but I am yet to get reputation...Thanks for the response

Comment: +1, and this should be the accepted answer. The only possible reason not to do this is a fear of external libraries (which I have myself).

Answer (score 1):

Where is the data comming from? If a db - you can do this very easily in the query on the backend with group by.

Answer (score 0):

A map seems the way to go. Direct access :)

Key: Element
value: number of ocurrences, or a list with indexes of the element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the solutions that have been posted the first thing that comes to my mind is to make a table "code - value" and encode the list using codes. It would be very space efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The most natural structure for this is a Bag aka a Multiset.

A bag is essentially a function from Object to Count.

Google collections has a Multiset however you could easily build your own using a HashMap.

http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html

Comment: thats great but how to get the count ?

Comment: Note that Google Collections requires Java 5, though. Other than that, this is even easier to do than my answer.

Comment: You can get the count by interating over the entrySet().

If you want to stream the count out you could extend the implementation to notify a listener when the count changes.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`Map.getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) for that, which is available since Java 8. As simple as that:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for (String s : List.of("Apple", "Samsung", "Apple", "...")) {
  map.put(s, map.getOrDefault(s, 0) + 1);
}
```

- The `getOrDefault` method returns the value to which the specified key `s` is mapped, or `0` if this map contains no mapping for the key `s`.
- The returned value is then incremented by `1`.
- The key-value pair is added to the map.

Or, using Java 8 streams - a combination of [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`counting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--) collectors:

```
Map<String, Long> map =
    List.of("Apple", "Samsung", "Apple", "...").stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));
```